# How to animate in css with a button

Tags: javascript, css

Sup, guys!

Im learning css, and im trying to figure out how to animate a div with a separate button

I just can't figure out how to use the button as a trigger

Here's an example

```
    <!-- html -->

<button id="mybutton">click me!</button><br>

<h1><div id="mydiv">hi</div></h1>
```

And my css

```
    #mydiv{
       border: 1px solid black;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       background: green;
   }
```

I didn't add the keyframes and animations here, but what im trying  to do when i press the button the div or "hi" slides from the bottom to top or something as long as it's an animation

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript for this. There's no solution with just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use javascript to add an event listener to the button and apply the animation to the div.

CSS

```
#mydiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 1s;
}

#mydiv.animate {
    top: -100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="mybutton">click this</button><br>
<div id="mydiv">hi</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    myDiv.classList.toggle('animate');
});
```

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b57q6son/2/) for you to look at and build off of